# Use open_in_browser icon or open_in_new icon inside native mobile app

Tags: icons

In a mobile app having a menu entry in the navigation drawer which points to a URL being opened outside my app, in the user's default browser, I msut add an icon to the right of the menu item, I got a design spec that uses [open_in_new icon](https://materialui.co/icon/open-in-new),

[image: open in browser]

But I'm wondering if [this icon](https://materialui.co/icon/open-in-browser) wouldn't be more suitable,

[image: open new]

I kind of feel it but would not know how to argument it.

Comment: What is the text of the menu entry?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles it's the menu entry showing the profile info (icon, name, e-mail), clicking on it opens a website with extended info about the profile.

Comment: If you don't mind, what's the exact wording of the menu entry? Such as "Go to store", or "Visit company homepage" — Knowing that helps clarify the scenario, and maybe that can be improved to support using the "open in browser" icon—or vice versa.

Comment: I already explained it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer which icon you should use. But there is a difference between open a link in a new tab to open the browser and show something there. The second will open a new app on your device which is different experience than open a new tab within the same app (browser).

So if you have a specific icon for this action you should use this for consistency reasons.

Whether the icon is clear enough or not is another question.

Answer (score 0):

[BrunoH provides your argument](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/145200/93969)...

> The second will open a new app on your device which is [a different] experience than open a new tab within the same app...

However, keep in mind, 1) people are more familiar with the "open in new" icon, and 2) interpret it more genarally as "go to an external link".

Comment: So we have a dilemma :)